# Getting .outerheight() of div with no set css returns wrong number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the height of a div that has no set height in css. When I hover over it with inspect element it says it is 92px high, however when I do the following in Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
    var heightSomething= jQuery('#something').outerHeight();
    console.log(heightSomething);
});
```

I always get "24". If I set a height in css to #something, then the console does log the correct height. Is there some sort of limitation to finding heights of divs with no set height? Thanks guys.

Comment: Please provide a specific example we can reproduce.

Comment: subtle side note - you are passing the jQuery reference as $ in your example. You should use it instead of using jQuery inside the ready function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try using load handler instead: { if there are some images/ajax }

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {    
    var heightSomething= jQuery('#something').outerHeight();
    console.log(heightSomething);
});
```

Comment: That was it! I didn't realise images weren't taken into account in document ready handler! Thank you

Comment: An extra question, I had to change the $ inside to jQuery, as otherwise the console would throw "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function", I changed them to jQuery and it works, is that okay?

Comment: Oh, ya here $ refers to event, not jquery. So use jQuery.